# Data Truncated using SUM

Tags: python, mysql

I have run a query in MySQL and I get a result back, while running it as a python script is giving me an error. I am unsure why this is happening. I am trying to get the sum of a single column and inserting that value into another column on another table.

Code:

```
HAND_HISTORY_DB_TABLES['Hands'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `Hands` ("
    "   `HandResults` float"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
HAND_HISTORY_DB_TABLES['Players'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `Players` ("
    "   `PlayerName` varchar(16) PRIMARY KEY,"
    "   `PlayerResults` float"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")
...

    def insert_player_results(self):
        """
        Insert Player Results
        :return:
        """
        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Players (PlayerResults) SELECT ROUND(SUM(HandResults), 2) FROM Hands")
            sql_connection.commit()
            print("Player Results inserted succesfully")
        except mysql.IntegrityError as err:
            print(f"Error: {err}")
...
    plyr.insert_player_results()
...
```

Error: `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1364 (HY000): Field 'PlayerName' doesn't have a default value`

Edited to include suggestion from answer below

Comment: I know for me in the past, at least, if something is getting truncated like this for a column in the database, it might mean that your database column is something that only lets you have one character of data in it instead of a string of data. Sometimes this might be like a `char` or `varchar` with a small length allowed. More info on `char` and `varchar` might be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html. I would recommend checking the data type and length of your `PlayerResults` column! Maybe the allowed comment length needs to be longer.

Comment: I believe I have already added that information in the code with `PlayersResults float`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `float` type up there in your code. Do you have any example data that could show what types of values you are using for the `PlayerResults` column? (Do you think the values are being truncated because of decimal places in the value or something like that, if there are decimals being used?) Someone indicated that this question needs debugging details; maybe there's more that could be added to your question that could help someone solve this issue.

Comment: So this does work in the MySQL dashboard, I get the result of `1.10`. I am inserting float values into the column I am trying to sum up. However, when I'm running with python, it's not working. It should be grabbing the same exact data from the SQL tables as the query does in the dashboard, from my understanding.

Comment: I've edited the code to include the precise location of the error.

Comment: error is on Field 'PlayerName' which doesn't appear in your create players table?

Comment: I removed the extra code that thought at the time was not needed and that was one of the lines by accident. It is there. I will update the OP

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where `sql_connection` is defined, but you are using a prepared statement, which requires that the second argument is a tuple with the actual *value(s)* to insert, not the string representing the query that would obtain those value(s). This would require doing two operations, one to fetch the results and store them in a designated variable, and one to perform the insert.

An alternative is to directly use a single query:

```py
    def insert_player_results(self):
        try:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Players SELECT ROUND(SUM(HandResults), 2) FROM Hands')
            sql_connection.commit()
            print('Player Results inserted successfully')
        except mysql.IntegrityError as err:
            print(f'Error: {err}')
```

Comment: `mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` as well as `sql_connection` is merely the connection to the server, taking the username and password for the sql server.